# Multiple user profiles / sessions in one CEF instance

Tags: chromium-embedded

Is it possible to have multiple user profiles—with separate cookies, history, local storage, etc.—running at the same time in one CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework) instance? The goal is to allow multiple browsing "sessions" side-by-side in one window (it's actually an OpenGL app).

There are two possible solutions I've looked into, each with its own problems:

#### Using `CefCookieManager`

This is possible to do for just cookies by [creating multiple `CefCookieManager`s](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=12534). However, there does not seem to be similar API for history and local storage, which are now still shared.

#### Using `CefSettings::cache_path`

```
CefSettings settings;
CefString(&settings.cache_path).FromASCII("C:\\CefCache");
CefInitialize(args, settings, app, nullptr);
```

The problem here is that `CefSettings` is associated with the global CEF instance rather than with each browser/client.

---

Is there a way to do this that I have not discovered?

Comment: Edited answer, there is a new solution.

Comment: @Czarek: That's excellent news, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only about cookies and local storage, and you host content using custom scheme handler or request interception, then you could use different domains/subdomains for each profile. See this topic for reference: http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11695 .

Regarding history, you could implement history on your own by using the OnBeforeBrowse callback.

In the topic referenced above it is also mentioned that it's technically possible to specify a different cache path per CefRequestContext (can be provided during browser creation). So working on a patch for CEF may be another option.

**EDIT**: CEF revision 2040 adds support for complete isolation of storage and permissions per request context, see comment #7 in Issue 1044: https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/issues/detail?id=1044#c7